# How to check if a radio button is selected, then check for the next radio button and show different content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

The desired situation is to show the `<div class="resp">` below the each radio btn when it is selected, and each `<div class="resp">` contains different content. When the next radio btn is selected, the previous `<div class="resp">` should be hidden and the selected radio btn should have the respective `<div class="resp">` shown below. For each question, there should be 1 response showing at the same time, when I click on the Q2 radio btn, one of Q1 response should be shown.

The current situation is that I'm only able to show all the div class upon selecting but unable to hide them away as desired.

**Javascript**

```
$(".resp").hide();

$(".radioBtn").change(function(){
    if($(this).attr("checked")) {
        $(this).parent().next().show().addClass('expand');
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="span9">

            <div class="qnstitle">Q1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
            <label class="radio">
                <input name="qns1" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="A">a) asdf
            </label>
            <div class="resp" data-qns="qns1">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris aliquet ligula mi. Aenean eu magna quam. In ultrices nisi non tellus molestie ut mattis turpis convallis. </p>
            </div>

            <label class="radio">
                <input name="qns1" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="B">b) bsdf
            </label>
            <div class="resp" data-qns="qns1">
                <p>Proin porta, ante eu feugiat facilisis, nulla erat porta dui, sed pellentesque orci sapien quis libero. Nam nec nibh metus, nec luctus massa.</p>
            </div>

            <label class="radio">
                <input name="qns1" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="C">c) csdf
            </label>
            <div class="resp" data-qns="qns1">
                <p>Donec metus nibh, pharetra vitae semper id, blandit non lorem. Fusce ut metus a dui egestas congue quis quis augue. Suspendisse sed nunc sed nulla volutpat pharetra at vel purus.</p>
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="qnstitle">Q2. Nunc sed aliquet enim.</div>
            <label class="radio">
                <input name="qns2" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="A">a) azzzddsaf
            </label>
            <div class="resp" data-qns="qns2">
                <p>Donec metus nibh, pharetra vitae semper id, blandit non lorem.</p>
            </div>

            <label class="radio">
                <input name="qns2" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="B">b) bzzzzddafdsf
            </label>
            <div class="resp" data-qns="qns2">
                <p>Aenean eu metus id dui tristique aliquam. Pellentesque non scelerisque nisi. Integer a nibh orci</p>
            </div>

            <label class="radio">
                <input name="qns2" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="C">c) czzdfasdf
            </label>
            <div class="resp" data-qns="qns2">
                <p>Pellentesque turpis libero, consectetur nec dictum eu, accumsan a sapien. Integer eget ultrices risus. Pellentesque vel orci purus.</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of span9 -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
$(".resp").hide();
$(".radioBtn").change(function(){
    $(".resp").removeClass('expand').hide(); // <--- add this
    if(this.checked) {
        $(this).parent().next().show().addClass('expand');
    };
});
```

Comment: +1 but using prop() is better for jq 1.7+: $(this).prop("checked")

Comment: It works for 1 question, but there is more than 1 question for mine, and I want 1 response to show for each question.

Comment: @roasted - Using `this.checked` is even better (in any version of jQuery). Why go to the trouble of creating a jQuery object and calling a method when the property is right there already?

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
$(".radioBtn").change(function(){
   $(".resp").hide();
   if($(this).attr("checked")) {
    $(this).parent().next().show().addClass('expand');
   };
});​
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdcLg/

Answer (score 0):

If this still applies there's a shorter version of this code. I asked the same question. Here's the link. There are two working examples and only two answers.

[Show/Hide Divs Multiple Radio Buttons JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135946/show-hide-divs-multiple-radio-buttons-jquery/16136075?noredirect=1#comment23051720_16136075)