# Show/Hide Divs Multiple Radio Buttons JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I'm helping my friend Michaela out for our web design class. She did the HTML, and I've changed just a few of the lines and added some divs. She wants it so if the user clicks on a radio button then the corresponding div is shown. All div's for her form start out hidden in a class "hidden_destiny". -- This going to be a series of nested div's and I may need to change the layout later.

Here's the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TuCQa/4/).
 Here's my javascript:

```
if ($('#radio_starwars').is(':checked')){
    $('#clicked_starwars').hide().slideDown('slow');
    $('.hidden_destiny').not('#clicked_starwars').hide().slideUp('slow');
}
else if ($('#radio_avengers').attr('checked', 'true')){}
else if ($('#radio_batman').attr('checked', 'true')){}
else if ($('#radio_xmen').attr('checked', 'true')){}
else if ($('#radio_harryp').attr('checked', 'true')){}
else if ($('#radio_lotr').attr('checked', 'true')){}
```

[EDIT] Updated code. Add id identifier to code and updated JsFiddle link.

Comment: so what's the problem are you facing? could you plz explain to us

Comment: First, you're missing a class identifier, a period, before radio_starwars

Comment: actually, it should be an id - #

Comment: @jqueryrocks fixed it and the div tag still will not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.fate').click(function () {
    $('.hidden_destiny').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $(this).slideUp('slow');
        }
    });
    var id = $(this).val();
    $('#clicked_' + id).slideDown('slow');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/pLqmS/)

Comment: Thank you!!! That saved me a lot of code. I was going to create an if statement for each.

What does `this` equate to in your function and how does the `.each` work? I can guess, but I'd rather know for sure.

Comment: `this` is the element which the function was called upon, `each` iterate through the selection of elements which in this example are all elements with the class `hidden_destiny`

Comment: Thanks. Also, I implemented the code and I noticed that the animations change if I click on the radio button more than once. How does that happen?

Comment: it's because the function is assigned to `click` event and will fire on each click, you can use jquery `stop()` method to prevent queuing. see my updated demo on how to use `stop()`

Comment: I understand why clicking the first one slides down. However, if you click on each one going down, then the animation reverses going back up. And Star Wars always slides down. I like the `.stop()`. I've actually used that before.

Comment: And I understand the `this` now. I added a variable and alert. http://jsfiddle.net/pLqmS/2/

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
$(":radio").change(function(){
  $(".hidden_destiny").hide()//hide divs
  $("#clicked_"+this.id.replace("radio_","")).show()//show div by radio id
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YZ9fh/

Comment: Thanks. I haven't seen the `.change()` or the third line of code. 
Also, your fiddle works, but the same code in mine doesn't? http://jsfiddle.net/TuCQa/6/

Comment: Because jQuery is include in your link.

Comment: Oh... I didn't realize that. I forgot about that. I have it included in the actual page.